# Bokeh Select Widget to Update Plot

Tags: python, pandas, bokeh

I am trying to build a grid plot that updates based on value selected from 'Select' widget using Bokeh.
The graph works but there is no interaction between the widget and the graph. I am not sure how to do this. The goal is to use the 'Select' to update dfPlot then follow the remaining steps.

Here is what i have so far:

```
output_file('layout.html')

select = Select(title="Option:", options= list(dfExpense['Ident'].unique()), value= "VALUE")

def update_plot(attr, old, new):
    dfPlot = dfExpense[dfExpense['Ident'] == select.value]

select.on_change('value', update_plot)

d = []

for x in dfPlot['Account'].unique():
    d.append(f's_{x}')

plt = []

for i, x in enumerate(dfPlot['Account'].unique()):
    dftemp = dfPlot[dfPlot['Account']==gl]
    source1 = ColumnDataSource(dftemp)
    d[i] = figure(plot_width = 250, plot_height = 250)
    d[i].circle('X', 'Amount', source = source1)
    plt.append(d[i])
    
grid= gridplot([i for i in plt], ncols = 6)
l = row(grid, select)
show(l)

curdoc().add_root(l)
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Someone else will probably give you a better answer.  I'll just say, I think you might be doing things completely wrong for what you are trying to do (I did the same thing when starting to work with Bokeh).

My understanding after a bit of experience with Bokeh, as it relates to your problem, is as follows:

- Using `curdoc` to make an interactive widget based Bokeh plot means you are using Python to interact with the plot, meaning that you must use a Bokeh server, not just use a .html file.  (as a corollary, you won't be using `show` or `output file`) https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/server.html
- You can still make a standalone .html file and make it have interactive widgets like sliders, but you will have to write some Javascript.  You'll most likely want to do this by utilizing `CustomJS` within Bokeh, which makes it relatively easy.
  https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/interaction/callbacks.html

I had a similar problem, wanting interactivity without using a Python Bokeh server.  `CustomJS` ended up serving my needs quite well, and even though I'm a novice at Javascript, they make it pretty easy (well, especially if your problem is similar to the examples, it can get tricky otherwise but still not very hard).